# Find all words that match and get the number of them

Tags: python, while-loop

My code should print the number of all the words replaced from Z's to Y's, using a while loop.

```
paragraph_list = ["She looked at her ztudent wondering if zhe could ever get through. You need to learn to think for yourself, she wanted to tell him. Your friends are holding you zack and bringing you down.",
    "I recently discovered I could make fudge with just chocolate chips, zweetened condenzed milk, vanilla extract, and a thick pot on slow heat. I tried it with dark chocolate chunkz and I tried it with semi-sweet chocolate chips. It's better with both kinds. It comes out pretty bad with just the dark chocolate. The best add-ins are crushed almonds and marshmallows -- what you get from that is Rocky Road.","The speciez are the Plains Zebra, which is the most common one, the Mountain Zebra, and the Grevy Zebra. Zebras are a short, stocky animal that is generally about 8 feet long and stands between 4 and 5 feet at the shoulder. They can weigh up to 650 pounds. The stripes on a zebra are very much like fingerprints."]

def findZ(): 

    for string in paragraph_list:
        print(string.replace('Z', 'Y').replace('z', 'y'))
    
    

findZ()
```

Comment: Are there multiple elements in `paragraph_list ` or is it just on string?

Comment: Count words with `Z`s?

Comment: @It_is_Chris yes

Comment: @Vishnudev I'm figuring out if it's able to count / return all the words with Y's and get the number of them

Comment: `count = sum(1 for word in paragraph_list if 'Z' in word or 'z' in word)`.

Comment: You can't count the y's afterward, because the string might have had y's in it before conversion.  You have to count the z's before.

Comment: @TimRoberts oh okay, so I'd need to access the words before, and then proceed with the function of replacing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sum` and `count` with list comprehension

```
sum(sent.lower().count('z') for sent in paragraph_list)
```